# HTML/CSS Navbar

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie when it comes to CSS and HTML but I really enjoy it and love solving problems and such, but I am stuck on this thing that I thought would be really easy, but it isn't. I can't seem to find an answer so I wanted to know if you have one.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

li {
 display: inline;
 float: left;
}

a {
 display: block;
 font-size: 32px;
 width: 140px;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
}

.navbardiv {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TestSiteCSS.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbardiv">
<ul>
<li><a href="Page1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="Page2.html">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="Page3.html">Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="Page4.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div >
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I just realized that I didn't even ask my question. What I am wondering is how to center the ul within the div.

Comment: what is the question ? and what is that thing on which you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center; /* This does the trick */
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block; /* Get rid of the float */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```html
ul {
        text-align: center;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

li {
 display: inline;
 list-style: none; 
}

a {
 display: block;
 font-size: 32px;
 width: 140px;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; 
}

.navbardiv {
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: #A0A0A0;
 height: 50px;
}

a:link,a:visited
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Ind is good, but here's another possibility. It depends on what you had in mind for your navbar...
The result: http://jsfiddle.net/2nambm6g/1/

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
}

li {
width:25%;
display: inline;
float: left;
text-align:center;

}

a {
display: block;
font-size: 32px;
width: 140px;
background-color: #A0A0A0;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;

}

.navbardiv {
margin: 0px;
background-color: #A0A0A0;
height: 50px;
}
```